# PATCH request ignored due to use of an 'auto-add' method in main controller

Tags: sinatra, rack

In writing a Sinatra app, I added a function to my config.ru file to automatically use additional controllers, while also running my main Application Controller (last line of code below). All tests passed up until the PATCH edit request, which was not even being recognized in the controller (I tried prying within the request).

See config.ru code below; why would PATCH (and I assume DELETE) not be recognized when using the method below to auto-add controllers? When I added "use SongsController...ect" that is shown at the bottom of my code below, my app worked like a charm. Thanks in advance.

```
require './config/environment'

if ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?
  raise 'Migrations are pending. Run `rake db:migrate` to resolve the issue.'
end

# auto-add controllers
Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "app/controllers",  "*.rb")].collect {|file| File.basename(file).split(".")[0] }.reject {|file|    file == "application_controller" }.each do |file|
  string_class_name = file.split('_').collect { |w| w.capitalize }.join
  class_name = Object.const_get(string_class_name)
  use class_name
end

use Rack::MethodOverride
use SongsController
use ArtistsController
use GenresController
run ApplicationController
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requests are coming from a browser then they will in reality be `POST` requests, not `PATCH` or `DELETE` (as `GET` and `POST` are the only methods browsers use). In order to use other HTTP verbs [Sinatra relies on the `Rack::MethodOverride`](http://sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#method_override---enabledisable-the-post-_method-hack) middleware which converts the request to the correct type if there is a hidden `_method` parameter.

You have this middleware in your config, but it is *after* your code to find and add your other controllers. This means that when a request arrives it will not have been modified to be the appropriate type when those controllers see it, and so they will treat it as a `POST` and not `PATCH` and ignore it.

The fix is simply to move the line `use Rack::MethodOverride` to before the code to auto-add your other controllers, so requests are modified before your controllers see them.

Comment: Thank you! I wish I had thought to try rearranging the code. Much appreciated